# Jetbrain Space Automation how to deploy an image to AWS EKS (Kubernetes)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, cicd, jetbrains-space-automation

I am trying to be able to deploy an image from a space repository to AWS EKS. So far I managed to successfully save my docker image to Space. But I stuck at finding a way to upload my image to my cluster.

So far I've created the following to save my docker image to the registy.
Does someone know how I could push this towards AWS EKS? Thank you in advance for taking the time help me!

```kotlin
job("Build Image and save to registry") {
    startOn {
        gitPush {
            branchFilter {
                +"refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    }
    
    docker {
        resources {
            cpu = 512
            memory = 1024
        }

        build {
            context = "."
            file = "Dockerfile"
        }
    
        push("<my-private>.registry.jetbrains.space/p/repo/repo/image:latest")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: my bad, it turns out I misunderstood the question!

I'm not an AWS guru, but to deploy to a Kubernetes cluster, I believe you would just need an extra step calling `kubectl apply -f your-service.yml` or something like that.

---

It is not possible out-of-the-box to push to private registries via the `docker` (now `kaniko`) top-level DSL, but this DSL is rather legacy.

Instead, use the [dockerBuildPush](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/automation-dsl.html#job-host-dockerBuildPush) DSL in a `host` step (instead of a `docker`/`kaniko` step).

One way to login to the private registry is to provide the credentials as secrets to the job (add the secrets in the project settings first) and do a `docker login` command in a `shellScript` block before `dockerBuildPush`:

```kotlin
job("Build Image and save to registry") {
    startOn {
        gitPush {
            anyBranchMatching {
                +"main"
            }
        }
    }
    
    host {
        env["REGISTRY_USER"] = "{{ project:registry_user }}"
        env["REGISTRY_PASS"] = "{{ project:registry_pass }}"
        env["REGISTRY_URL"] = "{{ project:registry_url }}"
        shellScript {
            content = "docker login -u \$REGISTRY_USER -p \$REGISTRY_PASS \$REGISTRY_URL"
        }
        dockerBuildPush {
            tags {
                +"<my-private>.registry.jetbrains.space/p/repo/repo/image:latest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As of June 2023, you can now also use the [dockerRegistryConnections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/automation-dsl.html#job-host-dockerRegistryConnections) DSL (but it's not available in the Free plan). In your project settings, you need to go to `Docker Registry Connections` tab, and add credentials there, and give them a key for reference, e.g. `"my-private-registry"`. Then you can simply add a `dockerRegistryConnections` block with a reference to your key, and the worker will login before the step and logout after the step, without the need for manipulating secrets:

```kotlin
job("Build Image and save to registry") {
    startOn {
        gitPush {
            anyBranchMatching {
                +"main"
            }
        }
    }
    
    host {
        dockerRegistryConnections {
            +"my-private-registry"
        }
        dockerBuildPush {
            tags {
                +"<my-private>.registry.jetbrains.space/p/repo/repo/image:latest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/docker.html#publish-a-docker-image-to-docker-hub) for more info.